# Querying and Filtering with Specific Keywords and Proximity

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, nosql, aggregation-framework

How to query the "car" collection, which stores a document for every car, and retrieve all cars that include specific keywords in their names. Then, find the latest "carInfo" document for each of these cars and return only the cars that are within a certain distance (X miles) from given coordinates.

Here are the schemas for the relevant collections:

```
Car Schema:
{
  "_id": "ObjectId",
  "name": "String",
}


CarInfo Schema:
{
  "car": {
    "$ref": "Car"
  },
  "address": {
     "location": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [Number]
      }
  },
  "timestamp": "Date",
}
```

I tried this but I keep getting:
MongoServerError: $geoNear, $near, and $nearSphere are not allowed in this context

```
db.cars.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        name: { $in: KEYWORDS},
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'carinfos',
        localField: '_id',
        foreignField: 'car',
        as: 'carInfo',
        pipeline: [{ $sort: { timestamp: -1 } }, { $limit: 1 }],
      },
    },
    {
      $unwind: '$carInfo',
    },
    {
      $match: {
        'carInfo.address.location': {
          $near: {
            $geometry: {
              type: 'Point',
              coordinates: coordinates,
            },
            $maxDistance: 5 * 1609.34,
          },
        },
      },
    }
  ])
```

Comment: `$near` can only be the first step of the aggregation pipeline. So you can start from the `$near` and then filter out, or you can calculate the distance "manually" without using `$near`

Comment: If you expect only few documents in this range, I would use the first option with a limit on the `timestamp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to do something like this:

1. Match only `carinfos` which where in range during the last week
2. Get their `car` data
3. Match only document which have the relevant `KEYWORDS`
4. For each relevant document, get the latest location of this car
5. Keep only documents which are the latest location.
6. You can format the response if you want

```
db.carinfos.aggregate([
  {$geoNear: {
      near: { type: 'Point', coordinates: coordinates},
      distanceField: 'distance',
      maxDistance: DISTANCE_IN_METERS,
      query: {timestamp: {$gte: timestampBeforeLastWeek}}, // for example
      spherical: true
  }},
  {$lookup: {
      from: 'cars',
      localField: 'car',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'carDetail'
  }},
  {$match: {$expr: {$in: [{$first: '$carDetail.name'}, KEYWORDS]}}},
  {$lookup: {
        from: 'carinfos',
        localField: 'car',
        foreignField: 'car',
        as: 'last_id',
        pipeline: [
          { $project: {_id: 0, timestamp: 1}},
          { $sort: { timestamp: -1 } },
          { $limit: 1 },
        ],
   }},
   {$match: {$expr: {$eq: [{$first: "$last_id.timestamp"}, "$timestamp"]}}},
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FNP8pa1fPTu) without the `$near` step as it is not supported